# Add external CSS file with custom backend setting

Tags: 8

I'm trying to add a external CSS file. The client wants to be able to change the url from the backend. Creating a backend settings form is not an issue, but I can't seem to get the file loaded in the frontend.

My code:

```
function MYTHEME_library_info_build() {
  $libraries = [];
  $libraries['mylibrary'] = [
    'version' => '1.0',
    'css' => [
      'base' => [
        'https://www.mywebsite.com/css/styles.css' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  return $libraries;
}
```

The fixed url will be replaced with a variable containing the value entered in the backend.

Comment: What’s with the keys and mention of css when you ask about JavaScript?

Comment: Fixed it, my bad! I'm also trying to add a external CSS file and I copy/pasted that part of my code instead of the Js part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_library_info_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_build/8.7.x) would be the right hook to add dynamic library definitions (definitions that depend on any run-time information) but it needs to be implemented by a module, as its documentation page says.

> Modules may implement this hook to add dynamic library definitions. Static libraries, which do not depend on any runtime information, should be declared in a modulename.libraries.yml file instead.

[`hook_library_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.7.x) can be implemented by either a module or a theme.

> Allows modules and themes to change libraries' definitions; mostly used to update a library to a newer version, while ensuring backward compatibility. In general, such manipulations should only be done to extend the library's functionality in a backward-compatible way, to avoid breaking other modules and themes that may be using the library.

If there are default values you can use (for example, using a local CSS file that is then replaced from `hook_library_info_alter()` basing on run-time information), you can put those default values in the .libraries.yml file, and use `hook_library_info_alter()` to alter them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_info_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
  if($extension == 'MYTHEME') {
    $css = theme_get_setting('theme_custom_css');
    $js = theme_get_setting('theme_custom_js');

    if(!empty($css) && substr(strrchr($css,'.'),1) == 'css') {
      $libraries['main']['css']['theme'][$css]['type'] = 'external';
      $libraries['main']['css']['theme'][$css]['weight'] = '110';
    }
    if(!empty($js) && substr(strrchr($js,'.'),1) == 'js') {
      $libraries['main']['js'][$js]['type'] = 'external';
    }
  }
}
```